# htaccess Rewriting a URL with a comma

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a url that contains a comma to another URL. The original URL also contains +'s (pluses) which I have figured out need to be escaped with a backslash, but the commas don't seem to be read properly.
Here's what it looks it like:

```
RewriteRule ^locations/New+York/Buffalo,\+Erie\+County,\+and\+Surrounding\+Areas$ "/locations/New+York/Buffalo" [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost got it right, you only forgot to escape the first `+`:

```
RewriteRule ^locations/New\+York/Buffalo,\+Erie\+County,\+and\+Surrounding\+Areas$ "/locations/New+York/Buffalo" [R=301,NC]
```